# Drawing a peer-to-peer communications model in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw an image illustriting peer-to-peer communications in Tikz. I have previously drawn flowcharts with relative ease based on the [Simple Flowchart Example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/).

Here is the image that I would like to recreate in Tikz:

[image]

My difficulties are:

**1.** I had to replace the Stickmans with clouds from flowcharts. (Not a big issue, I can live with this)

**2.** If I want to draw 2 arrow (edge) between client A and B, the result will be a two-way path (one line, with arrowheads on both ends) instead of two seperate arrows. I really want to keep two seperate arrows.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  A `->` produces an arrow at the terminal end of the line, a `<-` produces an arrow at the start of the line, and a `<->` will produce an arrow on both ends.  But, it really would be helpful if you provided a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problem was, that if I want tikz to draw 2 *lines* between *nodes* A and B, tikz will always draw the shortest connecting line between the nodes, hence the lines will overlap. At the end of the day I was too lazy to draw a stickman.

I had to define the connecting angles between the nodes.

My final solution:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [cloud, fill=red] (KliensA) {\textit{A} Kliens};
    \node [cloud, fill=green, right=5cm of KliensA] (KliensB) {\textit{B} Kliens};
    \node [cloud, fill=orange, below=5cm of KliensA] (KliensC) {\textit{C} Kliens};
    \node [cloud, fill=purple, below=5cm of KliensB] (KliensD) {\textit{D} Kliens};

    % Draw edges
    \path [line,red] (KliensA.60) --  node {A input} (KliensB.120);
    \path [line,red] (KliensA.210) --  node[midway,above,sloped]{A input} (KliensC.150);
    \path [line,red] (KliensA.0) --  node {A input} (KliensD.90);
    \path [line,green] (KliensB) --  node {B input} (KliensA);
    \path [line,green] (KliensB.270) --  node {B input} (KliensC.0);
    \path [line,green] (KliensB) --  node[midway,below,sloped] {B input} (KliensD);
    \path [line,orange] (KliensC) --  node[midway,below,sloped] {C input} (KliensA);
    \path [line,orange] (KliensC.90) --  node {C input} (KliensB.180);
    \path [line,orange] (KliensC) --  node {C input} (KliensD);
    \path [line,purple] (KliensD.180) --  node {D input} (KliensA.270);
    \path [line,purple] (KliensD.30) --  node[midway,above,sloped] {D input} (KliensB.330);
    \path [line,purple] (KliensD.240) --  node {D input} (KliensC.300);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption {Kommunikáció peer-to-peer modell esetén.}
\label{Peer2PeerFigure}
\end{figure}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: tikz-uml has an actor style for the stickman

Answer (score 4):

Something to start with:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols,positioning,shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
    Kliens/.style={cloud, 
        cloud puffs=11, 
        cloud ignores aspect, 
        cloud puff arc=120,
        draw, 
        minimum width=35mm, 
        minimum height=20mm, 
        draw=blue!50, 
             top color= white, 
           bottom color= blue!15,
        align=center},
]

\node[Kliens] (K1) at (0,0) {Kliens A};
\node[Kliens, above right=2cm and 2cm of K1] (K2) {Kliens B};
\node[Kliens, below right=2cm and 2cm of K1] (K3) {Kliens C};

\draw[->] (K1.puff 1) -- (K2.puff 4) node[midway,above,sloped]{A input};
\draw[<-] (K1.puff 11) -- (K2.puff 5) node[midway,above,sloped]{B input};

\draw[->] (K1.puff 6) -- (K3.puff 4) node[midway,above,sloped]{A input};
\draw[<-] (K1.puff 7) -- (K3.puff 3) node[midway,above,sloped]{C input};

\draw[->] (K2.puff 6) -- (K3.puff 2) node[midway,above,sloped]{B input};
\draw[<-] (K2.puff 7) -- (K3.puff 1) node[midway,above,sloped]{C input};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I did not use this solution, +1 for node[midway,above,sloped]. It was useful